# Problems with installing passlib

Tags: python, security

I installed passlib using pip install passlib, imported it, but when I try to run

```
passlib.hash.apr_md5_crypt.hash("password")
```

I have error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'hash'". Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

`passlib.hash` is not visible directly on the `passlib` module, so you'll need to import it explicitly. Either:

```
from passlib import hash
hash.apr_md5_crypt
```

or

```
import passlib.hash
passlib.hash.apr_md5_crypt
```